# Lock the contents of a TFS work item

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2010 and use work items and the changesets that are linked to them as the unit of change that gets deployed. I would like to put a work item into a "frozen" state, preventing any new changesets from being linked to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't lock individual Work Items so your best bet would be to set security on a particular area path and remove edit permissions to Work Items in that area for the required users.

When a Work Item is frozen it is put into that area and normal contributors wouldn't have access to edit it.

[Team Foundation Server 2010 Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.100).aspx)

> You can set these permissions by right-clicking the project in Team
>   Explorer, clicking Areas and Iterations, and on the Area tab, clicking
>   Security.